# How to check Method Function run

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check method alert run. After run have Condition

Function::

```
protected void Alert() {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "PlaySoundScan()", true);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "PlaySoundError()", true);
}
```

Txt Change ::

```
protected void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Alert();
   if( Alert()) {
     *************
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of not returning anything, just **return boolean value**. Change return type of Alert() function to bool and write `return true;` statement before closing curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

You could go with an `Task` (that's the purpose of those).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testificate
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Alert()).Wait();
        }

        private static void Alert()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

**old way**
You could call an event and listen to it.

Comment: No it seems to work for me. Remember that `.Run()` is a static method here.

Comment: a `Task`s purpose is **not** to get a return value from a method. There is currently no reason to mix Tasks into the OPs code.

Comment: You have how to run  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "PlaySoundScan()", true); in method?